# How do i upgrade the default version of python used in docker?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, ubuntu

I have this Dockerfile containing these lines

```
FROM "ubuntu:bionic"
RUN apt-get -o  update
RUN apt-get -o  upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -o  install python3.7 -y
RUN apt-get -o install sudo -y
RUN sudo mkdir -p /tensorflow/models
RUN apt-get -o  install -y git python-pip
RUN pip install  --upgrade pip
RUN pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

But when i build the docker file it gets stuck on the `RUN pip install tensorflow==1.14` and it shows a warning message

`DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support`

and also, it got stuck with this process

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.14
Downloading tensorflow-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (109.2 MB)
```

But the python version i've installed in my docker and in my local computer is 3.7.3. I dont understand why its using the 2.7 version. How do i go about making the docker use the 3.7 version of python? Since i want to install tensorflow with the 3.7 version

Comment: You can specify to `pip` which Python to use: `python3.7 -m pip install -U tensorflow=1.14`

Comment: Why not use a Python or even Tensorflow image to start with?

Comment: @barnacle.m upvote a question if it *"shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*. Vote on the *post*, not the *score* - see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/3001761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go around this issue. Even though you've installed python3.7, you have not installed a compatible version of pip.
To install pip that will work with python3, you should install `python3-pip` package and the run `pip3 install tensorflow==1.14`.

As suggested by others, you can build on top Python Docker image, e.g. `FROM python:3.7.7`. In that case you don't even have to install pip & Python.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. im new to creating dockerfiles, so it's completely okay to build on top of a python docker image than the one i'm using(the ubuntu base) ???

Comment: @void-louise You might want to look into [multi-stage docker builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).